# Detect Whether the first query is fininished in sql then run a second

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute two queries in Sql but i want to run the second only when the first one is executed.

here is an example to help understanding what i am trying to do:

```
-------------------------------
| id | name  | level | passed |
|--------------------|--------|
| 1  |Jose   | A     | YES    |
|--------------------|--------|
| 2  |Jeehan | B     | YES    |
|--------------------|--------|
| 3  |Sara   | D     | NO     |
|--------------------|--------|
| 4  |Sami   | B     | YES    |
|--------------------|--------|
| 5  |Lucy   | C     | NO     |
|--------------------|--------|
| 6  |Maria  | A     | YES    |
|--------------------|--------|
```

Now i want to select first users who has (passed=YES).

Then run a second query to show all rest of users.

I don't want to order them by `YES` or `NO` because i don't want them to be ordered. i want first query to give me random users but all has same value of `passed` column. and also second gives me random users with same value of the column.

here what i did but it doesn't work.

```
(SELECT * FROM users WHERE passed='yes' ORDER BY RAND()) UNION 
(SELECT * FROM users WHERE passed='no' ORDER BY RAND())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a single `order by`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
ORDER BY u.passed DESC, RAND();
```

This assumes that `passed` only takes on the values `'yes'` and `'no'`.  If it takes on other values, then filter first:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.passed IN ('yes', 'no')
ORDER BY u.passed DESC, RAND();
```